# C: macro not translating to int properly

Tags: c, types

I have a question about C behavior I don't understand...

```
#define KB 1024
#define FOUR_KB 4*KB

int main() {
  uint32_t a;
  uint32_t b = 24576;

  a = ceil((float)b/FOUR_KB);
  //want to get number of 4K transfers 
  //(and possibly last transfer that is less than than 4K)
}
```

At this point I would expect a to be 6, but result I get is 96.

Any explanation for this?

Comment: Check the macro expansion. Use parenthesis.

Comment: Please calculate for me `24576/4*1024` ? It's a) `6291456` or b) `6`?

Comment: Macros are just a textual replacement, so `a = ceil((float)b/FOUR_KB);` expands to `a = ceil((float)b/4*1024);`. To fix it, use parentheses in the macro expansion like so: `#define FOUR_KB (4*KB)` so that you end up with `a = ceil((float)b/(4*1024));`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplication and division have the same priority but compiler compute from left to right when push to stack :

```
24576÷(4×1024) = 6         // what you expect
24576÷4×1024 = 6291456     // what compiler compute, this mean : 6144 * 1024
```

You should use of parenthesis and `#define` like this :

```
#define FOUR_KB (4*KB)
```

Comment: it's not "priority". Multiplication and division have the same [**precedence**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), so they're done from left to right

Comment: @phuclv yes. you are right. fixed....